# Texstudio: keep Messages / Log panel hidden

Tags: texstudio

By default, I hide the panel since it takes at least third of the editor space.
My .tex takes time to compile. If I make a change while it compiles, then I need to stop the compilation and run it again. Whenever I stop a compilation, the panel pops up. How can I prevent that?

Comment: I am not sure (I think you can't)  if you can prevent the log window from pop up when pressing the stop button, but surely you can resize it in a minimum height, so it takes surely not the one third of editor window but about one sixth or even smaller, so it will not be so inconvenient for you.

Comment: There's a divider that can be moved with the mouse, and it determines the log size. I can't make it smaller than third of the text window.

Comment: What is your OS?  Do you have the latest version of Texstudio (4.3.1)?

Comment: Win10, latest version with Qt6

Comment: I have the same but I can make the log window definetely smaller than the one third of text window. I guess is a matter of display resolution, texstudio font size, window system font size.

Comment: Either way, I want it gone.